# JSF-PrimeFaces, How to refresh only the <p:layoutUnit position="center" > instead all <p:layout> ?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a layout with layoutUnit west and layoutUnit center, west side have a menu that calls another pages that render in the center side, the problem is that all layout is refreshed(west and center side) when another page rendered in center. I have follow code:

```
<p:layout style="width: 100%; height: 450px" >
                <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="230" collapsible="false" >
                    <h:form>                        

                        <p:menu style="font-size: 14px;  width: 95%;height: 420px " >
                            <p:submenu label="MENU">

                                <p:menuitem value="Students"  icon="ui-icon-arrowthick-1-n" url="pantallas/students.xhtml"  />    
                                <p:menuitem value="Teachers"  icon="ui-icon-refresh" url="pantallas/teacher.xhtml"  />


                            </p:submenu>


                        </p:menu>
                    </h:form> 

                </p:layoutUnit>

                <p:layoutUnit id="layout1" position="center" >
                    <h:form>
                        <ui:insert name="content" ></ui:insert>
                    </h:form>


                </p:layoutUnit>

            </p:layout>
```

And student.xhtml like:

```
<ui:composition template="../administracion.xhtml"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
            xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
            xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
            xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<ui:define name="content">
    <h:head>
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="styles2.css"/>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <p:panel header="Student" style="width: 90%; margin: auto auto">
            <h:form id="forma1">
                <p:panel style="text-align: center">
                    <p:inputText placeholder="Students" value="#{datosCT.cct}"/>
                    <p:commandButton value="buscar" actionListener="#{controlCTAlumnos.traeInfo()}" update="panel1">
                        <f:ajax listener="#{controlCTAlumnos.mostrarPanel(e)}" render="panel1"  />
                    </p:commandButton>

                </p:panel>

            </h:form>
        </p:panel>

    </h:body>
</ui:define>
```

I saw and tried some many ways to refresh only layoutUnit center  but doesn´t work in this case.

can someone help me??

thanks in advance.

Comment: You should not directly put `<h:form>` inside `<p:layoutUnit>`. Separate them all, place contents of each unit in their own separate XHTML file (usually under the `WEB-INF` folder) and include them in your master page template using `<ui:include src="SRC"/>` (The `<h:form>` tag inside `<p:layoutUnit id="layout1" position="center">` is redundant and is no longer needed). You can always use a container component like `<h:panelGroup>` to enclose the components of your interest that you want to update/render.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the partial update on form component inside your layout unit from your content page.

```
<p:layoutUnit id="layout1" position="center" >
    <h:form id="form>
       <ui:insert name="content" ></ui:insert>
    </h:form>
</p:layoutUnit>
```

student.xhtml

```
<p:commandButton value="buscar" update=":form"/>
```